# Can't Get Windows Authentication to Work

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, iis

I tried to create an authentication system in aspx using Windows Authentication. It seems to be the default mode for authenticating users in an intranet, for a company using Windows PCs. I enabled 'Windows Authentication' for my site in IIS, and disabled the other types of Authentications. This is my Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

What I have is a feedback provided by this line in my code (always false)

```
Response.Write(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString());
```

I'm not sure I'm doing all in the right way, but I've read many tutorials and all seems so easy... so, what I miss to do? I'm doing something wrong?

I haven't found anything that helped me in the implementation, simply all what I wrote seems to do nothing. Uh, also I don't see the Windows Auth Dialog

Comment: try `(WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;` and see what it returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved adding a row in 'Authorization Rules' in IIS. In my company we all are admin, so I added an allow rule for admin users and I denied the access for others. All works correctly now, I show the Windows Auth Dialog and with username and password I am able to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Check these requirements:

1. Windows authentication is **enabled** in IIS (you did it already).
2. Anonymous access is **disabled** in IIS (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244(v=ws.10).aspx).
3. Windows authentication is **enabled** in client's Internet Explorers.
4. `impersonation` is switched on in `web.config` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc(v=vs.140).aspx).

As far as I remember, that's all.